# Node.js実行中にプログラムが中断されて終了してしまう

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

以下のコードを実行すると標準出力に"OK"と出力されて終わるはずが、"OK"も出力されず、エラーも出力されずにnode.exeが終了してしまいます。
ただし、コード内の★行をコメントアウトすると"OK"と出力されて終了します。
process.onでuncaughtExceptionやunhandledRejectionをハンドルするようにしても、特に呼び出されているようではありませんでした。
どのようにすればコメントアウトせずに最後まで実行することができますでしょうか。
エラーが出力されないため、デバッグができず困っております…。

```
const RedisCache = require("node-cache-redis");
const host = "[Redisホスト]";
const key = "[Redisキー]";

const redisCache = new RedisCache({
  redisOptions: {
    host: host,
    password: key,
    port: 6380,
    tls: { servername: host }
  }
});

const main = async () => {
  await redisCache.store.ping(); // ★
  await redisCache.store.pool.drain();
  await redisCache.store.pool.pool.clear();

  console.log("OK");
};

main();
```